# Note 2 update problems

Tags: updates, 4.3-jelly-bean, ota-update, samsung-galaxy-note-2

Hi I got my note 2 from Kuwait. I am currently working in India. The last update I did on my note 2 was android 4.1.2 . Now when I check for OTA updates for my note 2, it shows that latest updates have already been installed. How can I update my phone?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Since you bought your phone from Kuwait, the phone has the Kuwait Galaxy Note 2 Rom, and still now the 4.3 update has not been pushed out in Kuwait or the middle east region for both the note 2 and s3. But for the Indian Rom 4.3 has already been pushed out for both the phones. My brother had the same problem with his s3 and since I have some knowledge in rooting and Rom flashing on an android phone I flashed it with the Indian Rom.

The suggestion I can give to you is wait for the update, when Samsung pushes out the update in Kuwait your phone will get updated.

If you know how to root or flash custom Rom on Android phone you can flash it with the Indian Rom just go and download the Rom from here http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/3/?download=25232 
And follow the instructions. 
For more information you can look here - http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/update-galaxy-note-2-lte-n7105-official-android-4-3-xxueml3-firmware-how-1429969
Just use the Rom from the sammobile site.

Remember if you don't know what I am talking about please don't try to do this you can brick(destroy) your phone for good.

Comment: +1 and this " Remember if you don't know what I am talking about please don't try to do this you can brick(destroy) your phone for good."  is very important advice!

Comment: @aasif ya I know abt rooting. Being doing dat since 2008 starting in my htc Google g1. Didn't wanna lose warranty though.. even triangle away fails at times.

Comment: The thing is once you flash the official Rom via Odin.. Your counter will be reset.. You don't need the triangle away application to reset the counter manually.. Unless after flashing the official Rom you root or install a custom recovery mode via Odin thus increasing your counter.